# I can't import the JDBC Client Driver from the derby package

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, derby

I have a Java Derby database running in Netbeans and I'm trying to connect to it using the JDBC driver. However, I cannot import the JDBC driver specifically from the org.apache.derby package.

What I've done:

- My pom.xml file contains the following Maven repo's

  ```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
      <version>10.15.1.3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbyclient -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
      <version>10.15.1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derbynet</artifactId>
      <version>10.15.1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  - The Derby db properties says the database is using the driver
    [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwgEH.png)
  - When trying to import the JDBC driver, it is seemingly the only thing missing from the derby import list [shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7g0n.png)
  - I have also downloaded the derby.jar file and copied it directly into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8-221\bin

I really can't understand why the JDBC driver specifically is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using release 10.15. In this release, the arrangement of the Derby distribution into jar files has changed, and this is probably affecting you.

Please read the [10.15 Release Notes](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.15.1.3.cgi) very carefully, and in particular please carefully look at the section "Note for DERBY-6945" for the details of how you have to change your classpath to access the Derby JDBC driver classes.

Probably, all you have to do is to include `derbyshared.jar`. But please read the entire thing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've read the release notes and, as you pointed out, found the issue. I decided to roll back to an earlier version which is now working for me.